# ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics cannot be installed by apt-get

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,I install it by sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics, but occured this:

```
Unpacking ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics (0.7.7-0trusty-20170222-143255-0800) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics_0.7.7-0trusty-20170222-143255-0800_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/indigo/include/moveit/srv_kinematics_plugin/srv_kinematics_plugin.h', which is also in package ros-indigo-moveit-ros-planning 0.7.2-0trusty-20160823-042449-0700
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics_0.7.7-0trusty-20170222-143255-0800_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256336/ros-indigo-moveit-kinematics-cannot-be-installed-by-apt-get/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
Please post error messages in English only. This looks like a serious problem, but I can't tell because I don't speak Chinese.

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2017-03-07**:
ok, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this a machine that has an earlier version of MoveIt installed?

There has been a reshuffling of packages and `.deb`s recently in MoveIt, so it could be you're running into some conflicts as a result of that.

Could you try and *purge* all moveit packages from your machine and then try reinstalling them again?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2017-03-07**:
Thank you very much, It works when remove and reinstall MoveIt